# How to compare two arrays for similarities?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, comparison

I'm trying to compare two arrays. Both of the arrays contain an ID for a drop shipper. I need to compare these two arrays, and every time a match is found, an sql query needs to be performed to pull out the email for the corresponding id. Here is my current code:

```
$orderid = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(orders_id) FROM orders") or die(mysql_error());
$orderid = mysql_fetch_row($orderid);

$purchasedProductId = mysql_query('SELECT products_id FROM orders_products WHERE orders_id = "' . $orderid[0] . '"');

$DSID = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM drop_shippers");
$DSIDarray = Array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($purchasedProductId, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $purchasedProductIdarray[] =  $row['products_id'];  
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($DSID, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $DSIDarray[] =  $row['id'];  
}

//compare $purchasedProductIdarray[] to  $DSIDarray[], then save the comparason in the same order as $purchasedProductIdarray[]
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Also, if you know a better way to achieve this please let me know!

Comment: Does the email address come from another table? Do the two tables have common key that you could JOIN them on?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare 2 arrays using `array_intersect`

```
$new_array = array_intersect($purchasedProductIdarray, $DSIDarray);
```

This will save the equal ids in the `$new_array` in the same order as in `$purchasedProductIdarray`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "save the comparison", you mean get a list of elements that are present in both, right? You would do that like this

```
$intersect = array_intersect($purchasedProductIdarray, $DSIDarray);
```

However, in this case, you shouldn't really be doing it that way at all; you can just get it from the database in the first place. It sounds like `orders_products.products_id` matches `drop_shippers.id`. If that is the case and your email column is in the `drop_shippers` table, then the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT products_id, email FROM orders_products
INNER JOIN drop_shippers ON drop_shippers.id=orders_products.products_id
WHERE orders_products.orders_id='{$orderid[0]}'
```

Also, the mysql extension has been deprecated; you should use mysqli or PDO.